ESRGAN Training Input
I want to use ESRGAN and train it to upscale satellite images. These images are:

16m/pixel (resampled)
RGB only
Sentinel-2 L2A


Is it worth providing a training dataset composed of .png files or .tiff?
Also, I tried to download some satellite images in .tiff format, and they appear way too dark. When I open them through SNAP, they look over-saturated. How will that affect training? For reference, I have provided some images below.


Opened through Windows Photo Viewer


Opened through SNAP

How will that affect training?
Any help is truly appreciated.
